# How can I implement a False Hydra monster in Call of Cthulhu?

Tags: monsters, call-of-cthulhu, call-of-cthulhu-7e

I would like to run False Hydra but in *Call of Cthulhu*.

A False Hydra is a creature with a skill to erase someone from everyone's memory after devouring them, what's more, it can be seen only in mirrors or when it stops singing (when it sings and you are within its range, you are hallucinating and can't see trails of blood, holes in buildings, etc.).

The climate fits perfectly and the story can be adjusted to the system without a problem, but I have one concern - Is there a Lovecraftian creature which is anyhow similar or at least some spells in the rulebook that can cause False Hydra effects, or should I just homebrew this creature?
From what I know the False Hydra is not canon in D&D as well, but I would like to know if there is anything similar in CoC.

Comment: This one? https://goblinpunch.blogspot.com/2014/09/false-hydra.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not knowing the creature or the source adventure you are referencing:

It is cthulhu, so as soon as you think "is this possible?" you are mistaken the basic idea of lovecraftian horror. Most of the entities he described were merely a perception of an otherwise nonmaterialistic otherworldly beings, that cannot be perceived by normal mortal senses in their original form.

If your Creature chooses to appear vaguely like a hydra, it may as well choose to do so. On the other hand you may as well play with the sanity of your PCs and have them dream about that image, so that they may be expecting something similar, which in of itself might warp their perception of it.

Since Call of Cthulu can be played with few to no dice rolls at all (I hope you do not plan to have your mortals fight the hydra) it is pretty much irrelevant how it looks, as long as your players are frightened.

Comment: False Hydra is a creature with a skill to erase someone from everyone's memory after devouring him, what's more, it can be seen only in mirrors or when it stops singing (when it sings and you are within its range, you are hallucinating and can't see trails of blood, holes in buildings, etc.).
And of course I'm not planning a fight with a monster like that, It would be impossible to win.
But I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: In that case i already see a small coastal village which immediatly appears mysterious by the offputting amount of mirrors and the obsession of some "less sane" townsfolk of pollishing their silverware as much as possible, so that is seems like you cannot escape your own reflection (which in itself can create fascinating situations).

Comment: @DeMo If you're wanting an established creature for at least a stat template, several editions of CoC have Nyarlathotep with memory alteration skills.  I do not have access to 7e books, so check him out to see if this version preserves that skill.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's already a mythos entity in CoC that encompasses the 'erase them from history' aspect of your 'false hydra' creature: **Aforgomon**. Not featured in the 7ed Rules, but it *is* listed in the Malleus Monstrorum (for 6ed and before). Aforgomon is an avatar of Yog Sothoth, with the emphasis of this avatar being placed firmly upon YS's aspect as the ‘god of time’. I'm writing from memory here, but those who anger Aforgomon are destroyed (after being made to wait for, potentially, a near-infinite amount of ‘time’ in a place outside of time) and once they are so destroyed they then fade completely out of history -- disappearing from records, photographs, people's memories, etc.

Since you have no plans for your investigators to actually battle your false hydra, this seems like a perfect entity to repurpose(?)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yog-Sothoth#Aforgomon

http://www.eldritchdark.com/writings/short-stories/21/the-chain-of-aforgomon